# Convert video with paperclip and ffmpeg in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ffmpeg, paperclip

I want to convert my uploaded video with ffmpeg, but I had few error. I use paperclip and ffmpeg but nothing happen. The structure of my application is one post `has_many` videos.

this my video model :

```
belongs_to :event
validates_attachment_presence :source
has_attached_file :source

after_create :convert_in_flv, :set_new_filename

def convert_in_flv
  flv = File.join(File.dirname(source.path), "#{id}.flv")
  system("ffmpeg -i #{source.path} -ar 22050 -ab 32 -s 480x360 -vcodec flv -r 25 -qscale 8 -f flv -y #{flv}")
end

def set_new_filename
  update_attribute(:source_file_name, "#{id}.flv")
end
```

and this my video controller

```
def create
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @video = @event.videos.create(params[:video])
  redirect_to event_path(@event)
end 

def destroy
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @video = @event.videos.find(params[:id])
  @video.destroy
  redirect_to event_path(@event)
end
```

The video is successful upload but not converted. You had any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replaced `ffmpeg ...` with `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg ...` and it's working.